# Force torque sensor simulation

Tags: ros, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to simulate a force sensor located at the tip of my robot. I'm using ros indigo with gazebo 2.2.
I went through [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contact_sensor&cat=sensors) and [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) tutorials and I was able to publish the contact state of a box model using `libgazebo_ros_bumper.so`.

What I'm interested in is to use a proper force sensor with the associated force controller. I didn't found any documentation about that in Gazebo Tutorials website and I'm asking in the case someone has had the some issue.

I also found [this](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/archive/0.9.2.tar.gz) archive of `ros_controllers` in which there is a `force_torque_sensor_controller` but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221702/force-torque-sensor-simulation/) by [mrslvgg](https://answers.ros.org/users/24627/mrslvgg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2015-11-29

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [filipposanfilippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21802/filipposanfilippo/) on 2016-05-14**:
Hi, I am also interested to achieve something similar. Did you figure out how to realise it?

**Comment by [mrslvgg](https://answers.ros.org/users/24627/mrslvgg/) on 2016-05-14**:
I answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally figure out how to do this. Basicly, I added the [ft_sensor plugin](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/gazebo_plugins/html/group__GazeboRosFTSensor.html) to my urdf.

Following my code:

```
<gazebo reference="${name}_fixed_base_joint">
    <provideFeedback>true</provideFeedback>
</gazebo>

<!-- The ft_sensor plugin -->  
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="ft_sensor" filename="libgazebo_ros_ft_sensor.so">
        <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
        <topicName>ft_sensor_topic</topicName>
        <jointName>schunk_wsg50_fixed_base_joint</jointName>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

some remarks:

- this plugin works with a joint, in my case `"${name}_fixed_base_joint"` is the name of the joint connecting the robot to the end-effector and it is fixed type
- have look at the plugin [implementation](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__ft__sensor_8cpp_source.html) to figure out the reference frame in which the wrench is given

Hope this can help. :)

---

Originally posted by [mrslvgg](https://answers.ros.org/users/24627/mrslvgg/) with karma: 191 on 2016-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mizu_lily](https://answers.ros.org/users/26610/mizu_lily/) on 2016-06-17**:
I always get an error that the joint I want to cope with does not exist. Did you have the same problem before? And can you tell me how you define the inertial parameters to get a right measurement? Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [mrslvgg](https://answers.ros.org/users/24627/mrslvgg/) on 2016-06-17**:
Sounds like probably you misspelled the joint name in the URDF. Consider that in my example code the parameter `name` contains the string schunk_wsg50. To be sure, fill both gazebo reference, and jointName tags with the correct joint name. All the inertial parameters of my robot remained untouched.

**Comment by [SorinV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30485/sorinv/) on 2017-07-20**:
What type of joint are you using?

**Comment by [AlanSixth](https://answers.ros.org/users/39494/alansixth/) on 2019-05-24**:
Sometimes I get the jointName: joint does not exist error too. It's certainly not a typo and I find that it depends on which specific joint on choose for a robot arm model with a mobile base.
A potential solution: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13109/cant-find-specific-joint-when-using-gazebo-model-plugin-libgazebo_ros_ft_sensorso/

**Comment by [JoshuaElliott](https://answers.ros.org/users/55920/joshuaelliott/) on 2020-12-09**:
This worked for me, below is the macro for the entire joint that I add the sensor to

```
 <xacro:macro name="fixed_joint_macro" params="xyz name parent child limit">
  <joint name="${name}" type="prismatic">
   <parent link="${parent}"/>
   <child link="${child}"/>
   <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="${xyz}"/>
   <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
   <limit effort="1000" lower="-0.0001" upper="0.0001" velocity="10"/>
  </joint>

<gazebo reference="${name}">
    <provideFeedback>true</provideFeedback>
</gazebo>

<!-- The ft_sensor plugin -->  
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="ft_sensor" filename="libgazebo_ros_ft_sensor.so">
        <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
        <topicName>sensor_${name}</topicName>
        <jointName>${name}</jointName>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
</xacro:macro>
```